# How can I set up routing in ASP.Net MVC to have requests for html files bypass the StaticFileHandler and be handled by the routing engine?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing, url-routing, asp.net-routing

Can I (without using runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests = true) route urls with *.html into default controller/action mode?

I need all requests to www.myhost.com/any/any/abcd.html route to www.myhost.com/home/oldlink with "link" RouteData key = "any/any/abcd.html"

I tried MapRoute with {*link} and constraints link = ".html$", but all request with point - catch StaticFileHandler...

Answer (score 3):

You can use a route like this:

```
routes.MapRoute("", "{*link}",  
                new { action = "oldlink", controller = "home" });
```

This will direct all requests to the following controller and action method:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult OldLink(string link)
    {
        //implement method...
        return View((object)link);
    }
}
```

The asterisk indicates that the segment is what is termed a "catchall" segment.  This allows you to match URLs of arbitrary length to a single route.  In this route all of the segments in the URL after the host name are assigned to the "link" string variable.

For example, it you enter the URL:

```
http://localhost/foo/bar/file.html
```

It will route to the OldLink method, and the "link" string variable will have the value

```
"foo/bar/file.html"
```

A couple of points to note about this route:

1. The URL pattern for this route will match **ALL** incoming URLs.  So any URL in your application will route to the "oldlink" action on the "home" controller.  With this route, you will not be able to get any URL to go to any other route.
2. By default, the ASP.Net routing engine will first check if a physical file exists on disk that matches the URL.  In this way, you don't need to worry about the routing system routing requests for static files, such as css or javascript files.  What this means is that if a URL is sent to your app that matches a file on disk, it will not be routed to the "oldlink" action on the "home" controller.  If you want to change this default behavior and have the routing engine route **everything**, including requests for static files, you need to add the following line to the "RegisterRoutes" method on your global.asax file:

   routes.RouteExistingFiles = true;

For more information about catchall route segments in URL segments, see the section titled "Handling a Variable Number of Segments in a URL Pattern" in this excellent [MSDN article on routing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668201%28v=vs.100%29.aspx#handling_a_variable_number_of_segments_in_a_url_pattern).  For more information about the RouteExistingFiles property, [see here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.routing.routecollection.routeexistingfiles.aspx).